# Align (multiline text)-nodes with tikzlibrary 'positioning'

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Before I turn to text boxes und coordinates, I'd like to know how far I can get with the tikzlibrary `positioning` only.

1. In the sample, the bottom line of boxes `n4`, `n6` and `n8` should be aligned *(seems to be the case, the small additional height/depth caused by `p` and `g` doesn't matter)*, the same with `n5`, `n7` and `n9`.
2. Furthermore, the left border of `n4` should be on the same vertical line as `n5` *(which is already the case)*, the same for `n6-n7` *(like `n7`: `node[right = of n5, below = of n6`)* and `n8-n9`.
3. `n10` should be at the same height as `n3`.
4. To put `n5` somewhat lower is no problem though I haven't done it.

Can I achieve some of this with `positioning`?

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle,
      rounded corners , node distance = 2em ,
    align=left]
    \node[anchor=center] (n1) {n1 Erheblicher Stress\\
      in fruher Kindheit\\
      oder spater};
    \node[right = of n1] (n2) {n2 Anpassung der\\
      Ausbildung von\\
      Cortisolrezeptoren};
    \node[right = of n2, anchor=west] (n3) {n3 langfristig\\
      erhohte Cortisol-\\
      freisetzung};
    \node[base right = of n3.north east] (n4) {n4 langfristig\\
      verminderte\\
      Neurogenese};
    \node[ right = of n3.south east] (n5) {n5 verringerte\\
      Serotonon-\\
      wirkung an\\
      5-HT\textsubscript{1A}-\\
      Rezeptoren} ;
    \node[base right = of n4] (n6) {n6 verringertes\\
      Volumen von\\
      Hippocampus und\\
      Basalganglien};
    \node[base right = of n5] (n7) {n7 erhohte Aktivitat\\
      im limbischen\\
      Cortexbereich};
    \node[base right = of n6] (n8) {n8 verringerte\\
      Fahigkeit zu\\
      Integration neuer\\
      Informationen};
    \node[base right = of n7] (n9) {n9 erhöhte Ten-\\
      denz, an Emotionen\\
      festzuhalten};
    \node[right = of n8.south east] (n10) {n10 Depressive\\
      Episode};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: lacking the final touch]

Comment: Please make your code compileable.

Comment: The easiest way is to define an identical minimum width for nodes that are vertically paired. For example `minimum width=2.4cm` for nodes 4 and 5 and `minimum width=3.3cm` for nodes 6 and 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking whether one can achieve the desired alignment with `positioning` only. The answer is yes, but you make your life unnecessarily complicated IMHO. Things get much more straightforward when you use the `matrix` library on top of this. Then the desired alignment is just a matrix with node anchors `south`. This requires much less tuning (only the `text widths` need to be made column-dependent if you insist on your manual line breaks) and the output is IMHO more convincing, too.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle,
      rounded corners }, node distance = 2em ,
    align=left,mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,
    draw=none,nodes={draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=10em,
    anchor=south},column 1/.style={nodes={text width=8em}},
    row sep=2em,column sep=2em}]
    \node[anchor=center] (n1) {n1 Erheblicher Stress\\
      in fruher Kindheit\\
      oder spater};
    \node[right = of n1] (n2) {n2 Anpassung der\\
      Ausbildung von\\
      Cortisolrezeptoren};
    \node[right = of n2] (n3) {n3 langfristig\\
      erh\"ohte Cortisol-\\
      freisetzung};
    \matrix[right = of n3,mymat] (m1) {{n4 langfristig\\
      verminderte\\
      Neurogenese} &
      {n6 verringertes\\
       Volumen von\\
       Hippocampus und\\
       Basalganglien}& 
       {n8 verringerte\\
       F\"ahigkeit zu\\
       Integration neuer\\
       Informationen}
       \\
      {n5 verringerte\\
      Serotonon-\\
      wirkung an\\
      5-HT\textsubscript{1A}-\\
      Rezeptoren}&
      {n7 erh\"ohte Aktivitat\\
       im limbischen\\
       Cortexbereich}&
       {n9 erh\"ohte Ten-\\
       denz, an Emotionen\\
       festzuhalten}
       \\
      };
     \node[right = of m1] (n10) {n10 Depressive\\
       Episode};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Just for fun: a style `matrix horizontal arrows` that draws the horizontal arrows between the matrix nodes automatically. (A style for vertical arrows is completely analogous.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{matrix horizontal arrows/.style={execute at end matrix={
\foreach \Y in {1,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{\foreach \X in {2,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}
{\path (\tikzmatrixname-\Y-\the\numexpr\X-1\relax.east)
-- (\tikzmatrixname-\Y-\X.west) coordinate[midway](maux);
\draw[->,#1] (\tikzmatrixname-\Y-\the\numexpr\X-1\relax.east|-maux) 
-- (\tikzmatrixname-\Y-\X.west|-maux); }
}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle,
      rounded corners }, node distance = 2em ,
    align=left,mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,
    draw=none,nodes={draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=6em,
    anchor=south},
    row sep=2em,column sep=2em,
    matrix horizontal arrows={-latex}}]
    \node[anchor=center] (n1) {Erheblicher Stress\\
      in fr\"uher Kindheit\\
      oder spater};
    \node[right = of n1] (n2) {Anpassung der\\
      Ausbildung von\\
      Cortisolrezeptoren};
    \node[right = of n2] (n3) {langfristig\\
      erh\"ohte Cortisol-\\
      freisetzung};
    \matrix[right = of n3,mymat] (m1) {{langfristig
      verminderte
      Neurogenese} &
      {verringertes
       Volumen von
       Hippocampus und
       Basalganglien}& 
       {n8 verringerte
       F\"ahigkeit zu
       Integration neuer
       Informationen}
       \\
      {verringerte
      Serotonon
      wirkung an
      5-HT\textsubscript{1A}-Rezeptoren}&
      {n7 erh\"ohte Aktivitat
       im limbischen
       Cortexbereich}&
       {n9 erh\"ohte Tendenz, an Emotionen
       festzuhalten}
       \\
      };
     \node[right = of m1] (n10) {Depressive Episode};
     \foreach \X in {2,3}
      {\draw[-latex] (n\the\numexpr\X-1) -- (n\X);}
      \draw[-latex] (n3.45) |- (m1-1-1.west);
      \draw[-latex] (n3.-45) |- (m1-2-1.west);
      \draw[latex-] (n10.135) |- (m1-1-3.east);
      \draw[latex-] (n10.-135) |- (m1-2-3.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

[image]

This require some manual interfering into code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usepackage{luatextra}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1ex and 2em,
every node/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners, 
                     align=left}
                        ]
\node (n1) {n1 Erheblicher Stress\\
               in fruher Kindheit\\
               oder spater};
\node (n2) [right = of n1]  {n2 Anpassung der\\
                            Ausbildung von\\
                            Cortisolrezeptoren};
\node (n3) [right = of n2]  {n3 langfristig\\
                            erhohte Cortisol-\\
                            freisetzung};
\node (n4) [above right = of n3.east]{n4 langfristig\\
                              verminderte\\
                              Neurogenese};
\node (n5) [below right = of n3.east] {n5 verringerte\\
                              Serotonon-\\
                              wirkung an\\
                              5-HT\textsubscript{1A}-\\
                              Rezeptoren} ;
\node (n6) [right = of n4] {n6 verringertes\\
                              Volumen von\\
                              Hippocampus und\\
                              Basalganglien};
\node (n7) [right = of n5 -| n4.east] {n7 erhohte Aktivitat\\
                              im limbischen\\
                              Cortexbereich};
\node (n8) [right = of n6] {n8 verringerte\\
                              Fahigkeit zu\\
                              Integration neuer\\
                              Informationen};
\node (n9) [right = of n7 -| n6.east] {n9 erhöhte Ten-\\
                              denz, an Emotionen\\
                              festzuhalten};
\node (n10) [right = of n3-| n8.east] {n10 Depressive\\
                              Episode};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the code become quite simple, if you consider @AndréC comment below question:

**Edit:**
regarding your comment, it seems that you looking for the following node positioning design:

[image]

For it you need small changes of code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usepackage{luatextra}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0ex and 2em,
every node/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     anchor=south west,  
                     text width=11em, align=left}
                        ]
\node (n1) {n1 Erheblicher Stress in fruher Kindheit oder spater};
\node (n2) [above right = of n1.south east]  {n2 Anpassung der Ausbildung von Cortisolrezeptoren};
\node (n3) [above right = of n2.south east]  {n3 langfristig erhohte Cortisol freisetzung};
\node (n4) [above right = 2ex of n3.east]{n4 langfristig verminderte Neurogenese};
\node (n5) [below right = 2ex of n3.east] {n5 verringerte Serotonon wirkung an 5-HT\textsubscript{1A}-                              Rezeptoren} ;
\node (n6) [above right = of n4.south east] {n6 verringertes Volumen von Hippocampus und Basalganglien};
\node (n7) [above right = of n5.south east] {n7 erhohte Aktivitat im limbischen Cortexbereich};
\node (n8) [above right = of n6.south east] {n8 verringerte Fahigkeit zu Integration neuer Informationen};
\node (n9) [above right = of n7.south east] {n9 erhöhte Tendenz, an Emotionen festzuhalten};
\node (n10) [right = of n3 -| n8.east] {n10 Depressive Episode};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your first solution, I'm nearly there. But n4, n6 and n8 should be on the same bottom line, as n5, n7 and n9 (and n1, n2 and n3) should be. The first I get by replacing `(n6) [right = of n4` with `(n6) [base right = of n4`, which doens't work for `(n7) [base right = of n5`.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann, see edited second example. Is now what you looking for?

Comment: Yes, totally -- if n3 were on the same bottom line as n2 `[base right = of n2` I guess.

Comment: You can move them on the same way as I do for the other nodes. See edited answer. BTW, `base right`  (as far as I know) doesn't exist.

Comment: `base right` does exist ("This key works like the left key, only instead of the east anchor, the base east anchor is used and, when the second form of an`〈of-part〉` is used, the corresponding base west anchor.
This key is useful for chaining together nodes so that their base lines are aligned.", p. 240 pgf-manual), though I'm not sure whether it is the best command to use.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann, where `base right` is documented?

Comment: Zarko: Page 70 and page 240 of pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann, indeed. So far I overlooked this! Now I learned something new to me.Thank you very much for info!

Answer (score 1):

With your help -- thanks to AndréC, Schrödinger's cat and Zarko -- this is how it should look like (in the world of Zelda, more of the arrows are strictly vertical, but this doesn't count). What I needed was tikzlibrary `matrix` and fixed `text width`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle,
    rounded corners, text width = 9em, inner sep = 4pt }, 
  node distance = 2em, align=left,
  mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,
    draw=none,nodes={draw,rounded corners,align=left,
      text width=6em, anchor=south},
  column 1/.style={nodes={text
        width=6em}}, row sep=2em,column sep=2em}]
  \node[anchor=center] (n1) {% n1 
    Erheblicher Stress 
    in früher Kindheit 
    oder später};
  \node[right = of n1] (n2) {% n2 
    Anpassung der 
    Ausbildung von 
    Cortisol"|rezeptoren};
  \node[right = of n2] (n3) {% n3 
    langfristig 
    erhöhte Cortisol"|freisetzung};
  \matrix[right = of n3,yshift=1.5ex, mymat] (m1) {%
    {% n4 
      langfristig 
      verminderte 
      Neuro"|genese} &
    {% n6 
      verringertes 
      Volumen von 
      Hippo"|campus und 
      Basal"|ganglien}&
    {% n8 
      verringerte 
      Fähigkeit zu 
      Integration neuer 
      Informationen}\\
    {% n5 
      verringerte 
      Serotonin"|wirkung an 
      5-HT\textsubscript{1A}-%
      Rezeptoren}&
    {% n7 
      erhöhte Aktivität 
      im limbischen 
      Cortexbereich}&
    {% n9 
      erhöhte Tendenz, 
      an Emotionen 
      festzuhalten}\\
  };
  \node[right = of m1] (n10) {% n10 
    Depressive 
    Episode};
  \draw[->] (n1) -- (n2);
  \draw[->] (n2) -- (n3);
  \draw[->] (n3) -- (m1-1-1);
  \draw[->] (n3) -- (m1-2-1);
  \draw[->] (m1-1-1) -- (m1-1-2);
  \draw[->] (m1-1-2) -- (m1-1-3);
  \draw[->] (m1-1-3) -- (n10);
  \draw[->] (m1-2-1) -- (m1-2-2);
  \draw[->] (m1-2-2) -- (m1-2-3);
  \draw[->] (m1-2-3) -- (n10);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: final touch]